# получение url ссылки на доступ к папке yandex

Tags: python

Как можно получить ссылку доступа к яндекс диску. Нашел библиотеку yadisk, позволяющую манипулировать диском. Но вот как получить ссылку доступа для выдачи ее пользователю понять не могу.
В документации нашел методы get_auth_url. Но он выдает, что нужен токен, а при его указании выдает ошибку, что нужен один аргумен, а получено два.

Comment: Насколько вижу по документации модуля `yadisk`, Вам нужно получить токен. Для этого стоит начать с самого Яндекса https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/. Также есть хорошая русскоязычная документация к модулю https://yadisk.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/index.html

Comment: @AndyPavlov я уже получил токен и зарегистрировал проект.